# Count(*) in Delete statement

Tags: oracle

How can I use count(*)>0 in a where clause of a delete statement?

My scenario is  `if count(*)>0 then delete the table1`.  I've tried this code:

```
delete table1 where c='n' and having count(*)>0;
```

But it's getting an error.

Comment: Delete all rows or only those `where c='n'`? Why do you want to add that count? Simply submit the Delete, it will delete matching rows...

Comment: @dnoeth - if you add that as an answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: @MaxVernon: it's ok,  keep your answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your query wants to delete all the rows in table1 where the value of `c` is `n`.

Simply modify the `DELETE` statement so it no longer mentions the `COUNT(*) > 0`, since that doesn't change the semantics of the query at all.

```
DELETE
FROM table1
WHERE c = 'n';
```